# How to delete and logout parse current user

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete the parse current user.

i'm using this code

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().deleteInBackground();
```

The user is deleted from server, but `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` still working

How do delete the current user user and logout in the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply call `ParseUser.logOutInBackground();` after `deleteInBackground()` is called.

If you want to use the callback version, read [LogOutCallback](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/LogOutCallback.html)